# Binding Model from Window to UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to bind `"CommonViewModel"` object from code behind with `"MainWindow"` and its children `"UserControl1"` and `"UserControl2"` in twoways mode

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Testing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testing"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1/>
        <local:UserControl2/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public CommonViewModel commonViewModel = new CommonViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = commonViewModel;
    }
}
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Testing.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel >
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CommonProperity1,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl2.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Testing.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CommonProperity2,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

My Object 
CommonViewModel.cs

```
public class CommonViewModel : NotifyChangeClass
{
    private string _Localtextdata1;
    private string _Localtextdata2;

    public string CommonProperity1
    {
        get { return _Localtextdata1; }
        set
        {
            _Localtextdata1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("CommonProperity1");
        }
    }
    public string CommonProperity2
    {
        get { return _Localtextdata2; }
        set
        {
            _Localtextdata2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChange("CommonProperity2");
        }
    }
}

public class NotifyChangeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChange(string ProperityName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(ProperityName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should work. It does not? The DataContext of the parent is inherited by the children, in case no other DataContext is set on the children controls.

Comment: Any binding errors in debug output?

Comment: Your code is working properly. What kind of issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, yeah you are right it works, the mistake was within the framework, nothing wrong with code.

Thanks anyway for trying to help.